# 2D and 3D plotting

Tags: plotting

have the following values:

```
      aa = {{{{{1112.5143463361717`}}}}, {{{{606.8260070924578`}}}}, 
      {{{{438.2632273445528`}}}}, {{{{353.9818374706004`}}}},
        {{{{303.4130035462289`}}}}, {{{{269.70044759664785`}}}}, 
   {{{{245.6200504898043`}}}}, {{{{227.55975265967166`}}}}, 
  {{{{213.51285434734623`}}}}, {{{{202.2753356974859`}}}},
  {{{{193.0810022566911`}}}}, {{{{185.4190577226954`}}}}, 
    {{{{178.93587388623757`}}}}, {{{{173.37885916927362`}}}}, 
     {{{{168.56277974790493`}}}}}
     aa = Flatten[aa, 4]
     bb = {1.1`, 1.2`, 1.3`, 1.4`, 1.5`, 1.6`, 1.7`, 1.8`, 1.9`, 2.`, 2.1`,
   2.2`, 2.3`, 2.4`, 2.5`}
        cc = {{{{{4771.1486600097305`}}}}, {{{{2602.444723641673`}}}}, 
   {{{{1879.543411518986`}}}}, {{{{1518.0927554576424`}}}}, 
   {{{{1301.2223618208363`}}}}, {{{{1156.642099396299`}}}}, 
     {{{{1053.3704833787724`}}}}, {{{{975.9167713656274`}}}}, 
   {{{{915.6749953554034`}}}}, {{{{867.4815745472242`}}}},
    {{{{828.0505938859868`}}}}, {{{{795.1914433349557`}}}}, 
     {{{{767.3875467148524`}}}}, {{{{743.5556353261923`}}}}, 
     {{{{722.9013121226868`}}}}}
    cc = Flatten[cc, 4]
```

Now, I want to make a plot that's look like the following:

[image]

I tried ListlinePlot but the x axis shows 1 to 14 instead of 1.1 to 2.5.

Then, I want to plot a 3D plot. Where, the X axis is bb, Y axis is aa and z axis is cc.

How can I do it?

Comment: `ListPlot[Thread[{bb, #}] & /@ {Flatten@aa, Flatten@cc}]`

Answer (score 5):

```
Panel[ListLinePlot[{aa, cc}, 
       DataRange -> Through[{First, Last}@bb], 
       PlotRange -> {{1, Max@bb}, {0, 6000}}, 
       GridLines -> {None, Range[0, 6000, 1000]}, Frame -> True, 
       BaseStyle -> Thick, PlotLegends -> {"aa", "cc"}]]
```

or

```
dd = Transpose[{bb, aa, cc}];

Panel[ListLinePlot[{dd[[All, {1, 2}]], dd[[All, {1, 3}]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{1, Max@bb}, {0, 6000}}, 
  GridLines -> {None, Range[0, 6000, 1000]}, Frame -> True, 
  BaseStyle -> Thick, PlotLegends -> {"aa", "cc"}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPointPlot3D[dd, 
 AxesLabel -> {"bb", "aa", "cc"}, BoxRatios -> 1, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]